# users not found in /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, user-accounts, acl

I login to a linux box with username `user1` and my home folder is in `/home`. There is another user named `user2` that has its home directory in `/opt/data/folder`.

If I want to check the list of users I inspect the file /etc/passwd in this simple way

```
grep user1 /etc/passwd
grep user2 /etc/passwd
```

I cannot find neither my user, not the other: Why is that? 
Is there any other file or command I should look to have a proper list of users?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That is because the users database is stored elsewhere, for example an LDAP.
Use `getent passwd $USER` to resolve your user.
Make sure you read `nsswitch.conf(5)` with command `man nsswitch.conf` to understand how and where can be users (and some other) databases stored.

Comment: My intention was to change the password of that user (via root) on that machine but it looks like I have to gather more information; seems that the user has not been added by doing the usual useradd , isn'it?

Comment: Exactly. Having root access to the machine doesn't imply you have admin access to an LDAP, though.